# Playing back logfiles with tf data for offline SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use bag data to run LIDAR-based SLAM algorithms (for example gmapping)  offline. For this, I use a erratic_robot in simulation with a separate launch files for simulated robot enviromnent and the SLAM system so both can be used independently.
If I start both my test scenario and my SLAM launch file at the same time:

```
roslaunch erratic_gazebo_no_slam.launch
roslaunch slam.launch
```

Everything works as expected, I get a map, a transform from map->odom and everything works as expected.

However, if I drive the robot around using pr2_teleop and record data using:

```
roslaunch erratic_gazebo_no_slam.launch
rosbag record /base_scan/scan /tf
```

and afterwards try processing the data using:

```
roslaunch slam.launch
rosbag play [the_bag_file]
```

gmapping manages to build a map, but fails to correctly publish the transform between map and odom. Any pointers on what's wrong are greatly appreciated. I was expecting to see my robot (or better, the tf tree) driving around in the map in rviz, but with the missing transform this is of course not possible.

/edit: use_sim_time is set to true all the time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9560/playing-back-logfiles-with-tf-data-for-offline-slam/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer my own question, one has to use the --clock option so the clock is actually published by rosbag. So the correct playback command line is:

```
rosbag play [the_bag_file] --clock
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0